# how to create back button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have 2 page. first is tableView and second is view
when I to click on any cell go on to next page (view) in way modal segue.
I want add back button in next page of navigation bar . this is my code in view page :
**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.lable.text = obji.Name;
    self.lable2.text = obji.Descript;

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Back)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}

- (IBAction)Back
{
    //I dont know that how return pervious page
}
```

Comment: If your controller is pushed  from a navigationalcontroller by default you get a back button

Comment: can u post the code of how your presenting the view push or present modal or add subView?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you said in your comment you use a modal controller

Add the following in **viewWillappear**

```
     UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Back)];
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

And in

```
- (IBAction)Back
  {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // ios 6
  }
```

Comment: It means when you click the tableviewcell how to navigate to the next page?

Comment: yes. I want change this. I want change Like dropbox application

Comment: sorry my friend I want when to click any cell go on to next page in way right to left and in next page when to click back button return pervious page in way left to right do you understand?

Comment: then you must use navigationcontroller

Comment: what? can you explain me about that?

Comment: Just look into UINavigationController by default itself move left to right and will push back the previous view on clicking back

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**

```
let backButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(back))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

func back() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }
```

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue, but I am using Swift. Here is the answer in Swift 2.2.

```
        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            let backButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(back))
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
            super.viewWillAppear(animated);
        }

        func back() {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
```