# navigaitonbar back button is not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

my problem is navigation bar button is not working properly,that is going forward properly but  not going backwards.please solve my problem i tried a lot.but i didn't got.

```
- (IBAction)showLeftSideBar:(id)sender
{
    if ([[SidebarViewController share] respondsToSelector:@selector(showSideBarControllerWithDirection:)]) {
        [[SidebarViewController share] showSideBarControllerWithDirection:SideBarShowDirectionLeft];
    }
    else
        [[SidebarViewController share] showSideBarControllerWithDirection:SideBarShowDirectionRight];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057327/how-to-create-back-button-in-navigation-bar

Comment: @PUVAN that is not working

Comment: Are you using any pods?

Comment: @PUVAN no i am not using

Comment: @PUVAN i will send u my programme can u solve it for me,i tried a lot but i am not getting