# Change back button of navigation controller

Tags: swift, swift3, uikit

I have this code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
        let controller = SectionsController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

In my class :

```
class HomeController: UITabBarController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, AddingProtocoleDelegate
```

And i want to change the back button title to `"Back"`

I've tried this in the sectionController viewDidLoad :

```
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Back"
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Back"
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Back",
            style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain,
            target: nil,
            action: nil
        );
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

But any solutions didn't work.

Help please.

Comment: Did you set rood view as a navigation controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create back button in navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057327/how-to-create-back-button-in-navigation-bar)

Comment: Nazmul, i set the home controller as root view controller, but i don't know how t oset the sectioncontroller as the new root view controller with the `.pushViewController` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton`

Comment: This just create a new left button in my navigation bar, but not a back button, just a button with a title of "back"

Comment: I found, i must use a selector in the button in action, and in the targeted function I call `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`. But a have a problem, Xcode say me that Expression of type 'UIviewController?' is unused

Comment: I found again ^, i must say `_ = self.navigationcontroller?.popViewController(animated : true)` because this method return a ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

The back button belongs to the previous view controller, not the one currently presented on screen. Try this and see if it works for you.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = "Back"
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
}
```

Swift 3:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = "Back"
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
}
```